Making chord diagram in R with orginal rownames
How to put rownames from original data into chord diagram.
The following link is for my dataset:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HdjZvWvkt1YuFuqNaiCp9OvmhX1nRohqswkxroZVjW8/edit?usp=sharing
I tried the following code:
library(circlize)
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("chord_diag_final.csv", show_col_types = FALSE)
rownames(df) <- df[[1]]
df <- df[,-1]
print(rownames(df))
data <- as.matrix(df)

chordDiagram(as.data.frame(data), annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1)
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 2.5, sector.name, 
              facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex=0.6)
  
  circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.5, major.tick.percentage = 0.2, 
              sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)


I got the following Diagram:

Instead of R1, R2, R3, i want the original rownames as labels for the sectors.
Thanks in advance!!

Tidy doesn't like rownames, use read.csv instead. To illustrate the problem, compare these outputs:
# example csv
x <- "c1,c2,c3
r1,22,33
r2,44,55"

Using read_csv, rownames can be assigned with a warning, but rownames gets dropped when we drop the column 1:
d <- read_csv(x)
rownames(d)
# [1] "1" "2"
rownames(d) <- d$c1
# Warning message:
#   Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated. 
rownames(d)
# [1] "r1" "r2"
d <- d[, -1 ]
rownames(d)
# [1] "1" "2"

Using read.csv, keeps rownames when column 1 is dropped.
d <- read.csv(text = x)
rownames(d)
# [1] "1" "2"
rownames(d) <- d$c1
rownames(d)
# [1] "r1" "r2"
d <- d[, -1 ]
rownames(d)
# [1] "r1" "r2"


I am getting following error:
chordDiagram(as.data.frame(data), annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1)
Warning message:
In chordDiagram(as.data.frame(data), annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1) :
It seems your input data is an adjacency matrix, maybe you need to convert it to 'matrix' explicitely.

@ShradhaSharma this is already a different issue. The original question, was how to get rownames to show up on the plot instead of R1, R2, etc. And using read.csv solves it. Accept this answer if you can see the rownames on your plot. If you have different/new issues ask a new question.
